# Selecting divs with data-canvas-width attribute and different widths on a page with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to select all div´s in the DOM that contain the data-canvas-width attribute and different floating numbers; there are hundreds of them and I need a Jquery selector that does just that, taking into consideration that the data-canvas-width attribute contains hundreds of different floating values. 
The div`s that I want to select: 
f.e.

```
<div style="left: 1254.81px; top: 693.131px; 
font-size:   14.1831px;         
font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.962576);" 
data-canvas-  width="52.97374357688933">

<div style="left: 384.134px; top: 605.71px; 
font-size: 14.1831px;   font-family: sans-serif; 
transform:   scaleX(0.92589);" 
data-canvas-width="94.31737477545221">1 l = 1,99 – 2,21</div>

<div style="left: 388.067px; top: 784.703px; 
font-size: 25.2143px;   
font-family: sans-serif; transform: 
rotate(-5.00003deg)      scaleX(0.871911);" 
data-angle="-5.000033687297824" 
data-canvas- width="56.151066266622706">39 % </div>
```

and so on.

What would be the best way to do that? Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("[data-canvas-width]")
```

That's what you are looking for.

To answer your new question:

```
$.each($("[data-canvas-width]"), function(i){
    var val = $("[data-canvas-width]")[i].attr("data-canvas-width"),
        point = val.split(".");
    if(point.length > 1){
        // do something...
    }
})
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like I need something more specific: I want to check the values of all those divs and if the value is a float value, then I want to perform something on this selector. What would be the best way to do that?